# Font disappears after a certain amount of cells in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

When trying to copy over cell styles from an old Excel file, after writing 32357 cells, the font disappears and when finding the root of the problem, I came across the error that it's throwing this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32768
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.getFontAt(StylesTable.java:210)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle.getFont(XSSFCellStyle.java:561)
    at Compare.writeRows(Compare.java:415)
    at Compare.main(Compare.java:44)
```

and to copy over the `CellStyle` from the old Excel file, I did this:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
newCell.setCellStyle(style);
style.getFont(); //throws error here
newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());
```

But I don't understand why it's doing that because when I do `rows.get(2506).getCell(2).getCellStyle().getFont()` it returns an `XSSFFont` object (the `XSSFFont` that `style.getFont()` should be returning) and doesn't throw an `Exception`.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache POI is limited to 32767 Fonts per workbook](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#WorkingWithFonts)

You will need to find a way to reuse the fonts and cell styles.

Comment: Let me know, what are you trying to do and I can suggest a way to reuse them.

Comment: I'm basically comparing it with a database, if 1 of the cells don't match up with the database, I highlight it red and the first cell of the row yellow. Otherwise, I highlight the cell green. I used the predefined cell styles in Excel, the ones with "Good", " Neutral", "Bad", etc

Comment: If it's just a small number of cell styles, then create them or clone them and put them in an array or a map.  And then, index into the array or map depending on what each cell should look like.